# command not found and unexpected end of file on a line that doesn't exist mac terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm quite new to mac terminal, not so much on bash, but I've been trying to correct these errors for a while, and I haven't been able of finding them.
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#change password of any mac user

# show users and select a valid one
Users=$(ls -1 /Users)
ok=0
while [ "$ok" == "0" ]; do
    echo "Users"
    echo "----------------"
    echo $Users
    echo "----------------"
    echo "Select user"
    read -e user
    foreach i in $Users; do
        if [ "$user" == "$i" ]; then
            clear
            echo 'User chosen:'
            echo $user
            echo "---------------"
            ok=1
            break
        fi
    done
        if [ "$ok" == "0" ]; then
            clear
            echo "There is no such user"
            echo 'Try again'
        fi
done
# get password and comfirmation
password=0
password1=1
while [ "$password" != "$password1" ]; do
    echo "Enter password"
    read -e password
    clear
    echo "Confirm password"
    read -e password1
    clear
    echo "Passwords are not the same"
    echo "Try again"
done
clear
echo "Password saved"
echo "--------------"
# get version and change password
vrs=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
version=${vrs:0:4}
if [ $version -ge 10.7 ]; then
       #LION
       launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
       dscl . -passwd /Users/"$user" "$pass" 
else
       #SNOW LEOPARD
       launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
       dscl . -passwd /Users/"$user" "$pass"
fi
echo "Password for user"
echo $user
echo "Succesfully changed"
echo "Press enter to end"
read -e end
exit 0
```

and the output that I get is:

```
:command not found
:command not found
mac.sh: line 65: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've already checked my $PATH and its correct.
Also I've tried running instead of "sh mac.sh" "sh ./mac.sh"

Comment: Try replacing single quotes with double in few places where you have them.

Comment: You also read password to password variable but they using pass which I don't think has been assigned

Comment: Those `:command not found` errors look like you have a problem with DOS-style line endings in the file; check with `cat -v mac.sh | grep '\^'` and see if it prints any lines ending in "^M" (carriage return) -- these are standard in DOS/Windows text files, but confuse bash (and other unix tools). Also, don't run the script with the `sh` command -- just use `./mac.sh` (you may need to make it executable with `chmod +x mac.sh`).

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson you were right, I have DOS-style line endings so I just tried writing it down again on OS X to get rid of them and the `:command not found` errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `foreach` to `for`
2. Change `$pass` to `$password`, because that's where you saved the password

If it still doesn't work, then change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x`, run again and paste the output into your question.

As a matter of fact, you shouldn't implement all the password input stuff. You should just let the `dscl` utility do that, like this:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/"$user"
```

I would rewrite your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

userhomes=/Users

echo Users
echo "----------------"
ls -1 $userhomes
echo "----------------"
echo "Select user"

while :; do
    read -e user
    if test "$user" -a -d $userhomes/$user; then
        clear
        echo 'User chosen:'
        echo $user
        echo "---------------"
        break
    else
        clear
        echo "There is no such user"
        echo 'Try again'
    fi
done

vrs=$(sw_vers -productVersion)
case "$vrs" in
    10.[7-9]*)
       #LION
       launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
       ;;
    *)
       #older
       launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
       ;;
esac
dscl . -passwd $userhomes/"$user"
```

Comment: Thanks @janos, you're right I don’t know how I didn't notice that earlier. Anyway, your implementation is much better so I think I will just stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the syntax of your foreach loop.  Bash doesn't have a `foreach` command, but it does have `for` loops that do the same thing:

```
for i in $Users ; do
  #do something
done;
```